# In cluster analysis, how to determine if a variable has impact on the clustering process?

Tags: model-based-clustering

I am using model-based clustering to split a sample into 4 clusters, and would like to know if gender is a determining factor for the clustering of this sample.

My attempt was to compute the in-cluster gender proportion for each cluster, and using the original sample (without clustering case) as a reference, then conduct binomial test where the `number of success = number of female in  cluster i`, `number of trial = cluster size of cluster i` and `probability of success under Ho = proportion of female in original sample`.

So in total I am conducting 4 significance tests wrt the original sample. Then given these results: (S=significant with pval<.05, NS=nonsig)

```
cluster        1         2          3        4

size          2729      1626       978      953

prop of F     0.505    0.450      0.315    0.470

sig(pval)      S      NS (0.636)    S     NS (0.398)
```

and original sample has female proportion of 0.456, can I say that clusters 1 and 3 have significantly higher (lower) female proportion compare to the original sample, so gender determines whether an individual goes to cluster 1 or 3, and female is likely to be clustered into 1 and male to 3 ?

My questions are:

1. Is the above conclusion valid ?
2. Should I also test if those two clusters have gender proportion sig different from one another ?
3. What if all 4 clusters show significance or all 4 non-significance ? What can I conclude in those cases?

Comment: By impact you probably mean "important in cluster partition", that is, associated with clusters? You did not say if gender is an internal variable (i.e. used in the clustering) or external (not used). And what type are the variables used there (interval scale?).

Comment: I think I am looking for more than just associated with the clusters, I'm hoping to be able to conclude that any of the variables affect how an individual is being clustered. Gender here is an internal variable, but I will also be analysing some external variables, I am just using gender to illustrate the situation. There are both binary variables and continous variables, so the function I used is clustMD which deal with mixed data type.

Comment: Please try search first. `clustering variable importance`.